# How to specify the return type of a function to be a (arbitrary) monad?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

In short, I want to declare a trait like this:

```
trait Test {
    def test(amount: Int): A[Int] // where A must be a Monad
}
```

so that I can use it without knowing what monad that `A` is, like:

```
class Usecase {
    def someFun(t: Test) = for { i <- t.test(3) } yield i+1
}
```

---

more details...

essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
class MonadResultA extends SomeUnknownType {
    // the base function
    def test(s: String): Option[Int] = Some(3)
}

class MonadResultB(a: MonadResultA) extends SomeUnknownType {
    // added a layer of Writer on top of base function
    def test(s: String): WriterT[Option, String, Int] = WriterT.put(a.test(s))("the log")
}

class Process {
    def work(x: SomeUnknownType) {
        for {
            i <- x.test("key")
        } yield i+1
    }
}
```

I wanted to be able to pass any instances of `MonadResultA` **or** `MonadResultB` without making any changes to the function `work`.
The missing piece is that `SomeUnknowType`, which I guess should have a `test` like below to make the `work` function compiles.

```
trait SomeUnknowType {
    def test(s: String): T[Int] // where T must be some Monad
}
```

---

As I've said, I'm still learning this monad thing... if you find my code is not the *right* way to do it, you're more than welcomed to point it out~

thanks a lot~~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a type class called `Monad` you can just write

```
def test[A:Monad](amount: Int): A[Int]
```

The compiler will require that there is an implicit of type `Monad[A]` in scope when test is called.

**EDIT:**
I'm still not sure what you're looking for, but you could package up a monad value with its corresponding type class in a trait like this:

```
//trait that holds value and monad
trait ValueWithMonad[E] {
  type A[+E]
  type M <: Monad[A]
  val v:A[E]
  val m:M
}

object M {

  //example implementation of test method
  def test(amount:Int):ValueWithMonad[Int] = new ValueWithMonad[Int] {
    type A[+E] = Option[E]
    type M = Monad[Option]
    override val v = Option(amount)
    override val m = OptionMonad
  }

  //test can now be used like this
  def t {
    val vwm = test(1)
    vwm.m.bind(vwm.v, (x:Int) => {
      println(x)
      vwm.m.ret(x)
    })
  }
}

trait Monad[A[_]] {
  def bind[E,E2](m:A[E], f:E=>A[E2]):A[E2]
  def ret[E](e:E):A[E]
}

object OptionMonad extends Monad[Option] {
  override def bind[E,E2](m:Option[E], f:E=>Option[E2]) = m.flatMap(f)
  override def ret[E](e:E) = Some(e)
}
```

Comment: But then the calling code must know exactly what A is, and more importantly, the return type must depend on the A provided when the function is called, that cannot achive what I wanted to do...  if you have the time, please take a look at the detailed description of my problem~ thanks~

Comment: I suggest you simplify your code so that it is reduced to the problem and doesn't contain any irrelevant things from your project. tl;dr

Comment: @Chris of course the calling code must know what type it's going to get back. Scala is statically typed. It won't know the runtime class, but it has know the type for it to compile. If all you know is that you're getting back some sort of Monad[Int], the return type must be Monad[Int].

Comment: I've tried to simplify my code, hope that makes the problem clearer~

Comment: I'm still digesting what you've written, seems like that can solve the problem. With the method test returning a `ValueWithMonad` for every implementation, the `t` method could be defined with it. I can see that your definition of Monad is a bit different from that from scalaz, like the `bind` method it takes a f:A=>M[B], is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, the bind method is less general, but I don't think it changes anything about the general approach.

Comment: fixed the monad definition, nothing else needs to change

Comment: do you think it is possibile to make ‘ValueWithMonad‘ an instance of monad? I've tried and found that it's impossibile to write the bind method...

Comment: maybe you should post your attempts in a separate question